# RMagick posterize and other does not work

Tags: ruby, rmagick

I guy's 
i have write this code:

```
require 'RMagick'
include Magick

img = Image.read("small_img.gif").first
img.posterize
img.display
exit
```

the result of image don't change
i've tested blur_image, oil_paint, other but don't work
only rotate! work form me, maybe have writed too bad the code?
p.s. sorry for  my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
img.posterize
```

returns a new image object, it does not alter the image in place. So if you do the following

```
new_img = img.posterize
new_img.display
```

you should see results of your test.

The same applies to a lot of rmagic transformations.